Nudged Elastic Band vs Linear Synchronous Transit/Quadratic Synchronous Transit Method
I have noticed that both the CI-NEB and LST/QST methods have been used in the literature for calculating the transition state energies and migration barriers. Since the CI-NEB method calculates the entire migration pathway, while the LST/QST method directly calculates the transition state energy, I am wondering whether a significant difference is expected in the energetics of both methods and why one would use the latter over the former.
